# HTTP Request originated from HTTP Server

Tags: http

I have a HTTP Client connected to a HTTP Server - HTTP 1.1 and the TCP connection is persisted.
HTTP client is sending request over an interval and receives response from server.

**In this persisted TCP connection, can HTTP Server send a HTTP request over the existing TCP connection to the HTTP client?** (We need this - say the page has an information which is changing dynamically (Example: some one hit a goal / some one hit six / some one took a wicket / some VVVIP killed / etc).

Does the existing standard allows HTTP server to send HTTP request to its connected client?

Note: I am not looking at page refresh / other web or application protocols like AJAX...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a server push, and no, it is not supported by HTTP/1.1.

Requests headers are distinct from response headers, such that the [push mechanism](http://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PUSH_PROMISE) defined in the proposed HTTP/2 spec works by combining together the headers of the request and response.

You should look at [AJAX/Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) because it essentially implements what you describe: the client-side application defines a method to receive any kind of game action, and then the server specifies which action occurred for each push.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this issue. My only problem is 
---> Does the existing HTTP 1.1 standard allows HTTP server to send HTTP request to its connected client?

Comment: @user3675190 Again, no.